# Atualizar TextView no onResume

Tags: android, android-fragment

```
package br.com.automaserv.stocserv.fragments;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;
import br.com.automaserv.stocserv.R;
import br.com.automaserv.stocserv.StocApplication;
import br.com.automaserv.stocserv.activities.FichaItemProdutoActivity;
import br.com.automaserv.stocserv.model.ORM;

public class ListaProdutosVendaFragment extends StocStringListFragment<ORM.ItemVenda, FichaItemProdutoActivity> {

private TextView tvSubtotal;
private StocApplication app;

public ListaProdutosVendaFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    loadAllOnResume = true;

    tvSubtotal   = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSubTotal);

    app = getApp();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    startTask();
}

private void startTask() {
    new Task().execute();
}
private class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private String text;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Log.d("test","doInBackground");
        this.text = "funcionou";
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.d("test","onPostExecute");
        tvSubtotal.setText(text);
    }
}

@Override
protected Class<FichaItemProdutoActivity> getActivityClassName() {
    return FichaItemProdutoActivity.class;
}

@Override
protected void loadAll() {
    replaceData( app.itensVenda );
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    List<ORM.Produto> res = ORM.Produto.buscar( query );
    replaceData(res);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected int getLayoutResourceId() {
    return R.layout.lista_produtos_venda_fragment;
}
```

}

Ola a todos! Eu possuo o seguinte fragmento descrito acima e preciso atualizar o conteúdo do TextView tvSubtotal sempre que o fragmento for reexibido. O fragmento é uma lista de itens e deve exibir a soma dos itens adicionados. Porem estou sempre obtendo o erro "did not call through to super.onResume()"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você não deve estar chamando o super.onResume();

Tente fazer dessa forma:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
}
```

Obrigatóriamente, chamando o **@Override** e o **super.onResume**

Comment: So complementado, todos os metodos do cliclo de vida da activity devem, antes de tudo, chamar seus respectivos metodos da classe pai, `super.onResume()`, `super.onPause()`, `super.onStop()` e por ai vai...

Comment: Complementando mais um pouco, deve passar a atualização que deseja dentro do `onResume()`, depois de `super.OnResume()`.